# Can I lie saying an affirmation onto something that doesn't exists

Tags: logic

If someone asks me where I live, and I give an addres I know doesn't exists, for example, "Sunset Boulevard 1600", being the address number 1600 inexistent, ¿Am I lying?

If I am lying, then I don´t live in Sunset Boulevard 1600, which is true.

If am not lying, I live in Sunset Boulevard 1600, but this doesn't exists, so it could be a vacous truth.

The last sentence confuses me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Vacuous truths are in the form of a material conditional P->Q, such that the antecedent P is false (thus regardless of what truth value Q takes, P->Q is true by the semantics of material conditional). But here, it doesn't seem like a conditional is involved: if we take F to mean '...resides at Sunset Boulevard 1600', and a to be you, then we can just express what you said as Fa. If Fa is false, then you do not reside at Sunset Boulevard 1600; if Fa is true, then you do - there is no material conditional and so I don't think vacuous truth is involved.

Comment: Well your use of the word LYING has issues. The word LYING expresses that the person intentionally makes a false statement. That is you know the answer is wrong & you are trying to deceive someone else.  Many people in SLANG use the word LYING incorrectly by expressing any false statement as a LIE. So if I honestly get the answer to a question wrong that  person with slang may consider any false statement a lie. To these people there are no mistakes & seemingly no one can be ignorant of knowledge.  If I get the any rational question wrong I could be ignorant & not lying. Which version is used?

Comment: Yes, in the sense if its false, not knowing before hand the truth.